# Using apache_avro crate, how could I reference a sub_schema in a top_schema?

Tags: rust, avro

I am trying to write nested records using the Schema::parse_*list method (so the top_schema references the sub*_schema). Appending to the writer raises an error.

By the way, if I write plainly the top_schema with nested fields, it works.

How could I reference a sub_*schema in a top*_schema?

```
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::Write;
use apache_avro::{Schema, Writer};
use apache_avro::types::Record;

use access_layer::schemas::part_schema_to_json_file;

fn write_data (top_schema: &Schema, sub_schema: &Schema) {
    let mut sub_record = Record::new(&sub_schema).unwrap();
    sub_record.put("streetaddress", "123 Main St.");
    sub_record.put("city", "Anytown");

    let mut top_record = Record::new(&top_schema).unwrap();
    top_record.put("firstname", "John");
    top_record.put("lastname", "Doe");
    top_record.put("address", sub_record);


    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .open("customer.avro")
        .unwrap();

    let mut writer = Writer::new(&top_schema, &mut file);
    writer.append(top_record).unwrap();
    writer.flush().unwrap();
}

fn create_data_without_schema_references(){
    let top_schema = Schema::parse_str(r#"
    {
        "name": "Customer",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "lastname", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "address", "type":
                {
                    "name": "AddressRecord",
                    "type": "record",
                    "fields": [
                    {"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},
                    {"name": "city", "type": "string"}
                    ]}
            }
        ]
    }
    "#).unwrap();

    let sub_schema = Schema::parse_str(r#"
    {
        "name": "AddressRecord",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "city", "type": "string"}
        ]
    }
    "#).unwrap();

    write_data(&top_schema, &sub_schema);
}

fn create_data_with_schema_reference(){

    let top_schema = r#"
    {
        "name": "Customer",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "firstname", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "lastname", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "address", "type":"AddressRecord"}
        ]
    }
    "#;

    let sub_schema = r#"
    {
        "name": "AddressRecord",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "city", "type": "string"}
        ]
    }
    "#;

    let schemas = Schema::parse_list(&[sub_schema, top_schema]).unwrap();

    write_data(&schemas[1], &schemas[0]);
}

fn main() {
    create_data_without_schema_references(); // This works
    create_data_with_schema_reference(); //This does not.
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SchemaResolutionError(Name { name: "AddressRecord", namespace: None })', src/main.rs:30:31
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the rust library in particular, but since you're using plain strings, you can simply inline nested records

```
"fields": [
...
{"name": "address", "type": {
  "name": "AddressRecord", 
  "type": "record",
        "fields": [
            {"name": "streetaddress", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "city", "type": "string"}
        ]
    }}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the approach I am show in the method "create_data_without_schema_reference", and while this is a valid approach but I am looking specifically into referencing a schema into another. But I ll use this approach if I can make the reference works.